# Python user input; 3 stage passcode sequence not working as expected

Tags: python, input

EDIT: Sorry guys I just can't get the images to load for some reason =/

I've had a really hard look around the internet and done a fair few different versions of this program, but for some reason it won't work as intended.

Below is a description of the question as well as the input and output expected. Below that is my code:

```
target = "pizza", "cat", "emu"

u_input = input("Enter a passcode: ")

while True:    
    if u_input == target[0]:
        u_input = input("Enter a passcode: ")
        if u_input == target[1]:
            u_input = input("Enter a passcode: ")
            if u_input == target[2]:
                print("Passcode accepted!")
                break
            else:
                u_input = input("Enter a passcode: ")
        else:
            u_input = input("Enter a passcode: ")
    else:
        u_input = input("Enter a passcode: ")
```

I'm certain the issue is with the duplicate input that occurs with 'pizza'. I know this seems trivial, but I've tried so, so many different solutions to this and I feel like I'm missing something silly here. I've poured through my lecture slides, gone over the labs again, and run it in different coding environments all to the same effect.

Kind of losing my mind here. Hope anyone can help and please excuse me if I've made any formatting errors or totally missed another question (I have a learning disability).

EDIT:

The output and input expected

Input:
[image]

At this point, it should print 'Passcode accepted!'. However, it oddly does not.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: Most of all, the code works just fine for me.  Since you neglected to supply the problem input, there's not much we can do in support.

Comment: @Prune, while inline input/output would be nicer, this question has had an MRE, including inputs/outputs since before your first comment.

Comment: @xdhmoore Please refer to the MRE documentation.  Even now, the question is not complete.

Comment: @Prune, I've reread that page, but I don't see anything that jumps out at me, aside from maybe some more debugging could have been done to narrow it down. There were inputs/outputs/smallish targeted code snippet/indications of attempts made. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Inputs and results are required in text and in the question, neither an image nor on another page.  These are to make the question and answer accessible to future visitors -- which, after all, is the charter of this site.

Comment: I agree that inputs/outputs should be inline, and are preferred in text, but I don't see anywhere in that document directing people to do that. To me it sounds like the focus on text is around code as text instead of images, for obvious reasons...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231190/discussion-between-xdhmoore-and-prune).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when `pizza` is repeated twice, the 2nd time the if statement `if u_input == target[1]:` is only looking for the word `cat` and then restarts the loop if that is wrong.

I added some numbers to distinguish the outputs:

```
target = "pizza", "cat", "emu"

u_input = input("Enter a passcode0: ")

while True:
    if u_input == target[0]:
        u_input = input("Enter a passcode1 ")
        if u_input == target[1]:
            u_input = input("Enter a passcode2 ")
            if u_input == target[2]:
                print("Passcode accepted!")
                break
            else:
                u_input = input("Enter a passcode3: ")
        else:
            u_input = input("Enter a passcode4: ")
    else:
        u_input = input("Enter a passcode5: ")
```

I get the following:

```
> python3 so_test.py
Enter a passcode0: dog
Enter a passcode5: pizza
Enter a passcode1 cat
Enter a passcode2 frog
Enter a passcode3: emu
Enter a passcode5: pizza
Enter a passcode1 pizza
Enter a passcode4: cat
Enter a passcode5: emu
Enter a passcode5:
```

You can see that when `pizza` is entered the 2nd time in a row, it ends up at the comparison `if u_input == target[1]`, looking for `cat`. However, this `pizza` does actually begin a valid password sequence.

One way to fix this is to keep track of the last 3 entered inputs in a list or in 3 variables: `last`, `prev`, `prevprev`, or whatever. Then you can check if the last three things entered were correct instead of coding that order into the if statements. (and you probably won't need as many `if`s).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because every time you get the passcode wrong it returns to start of the loop.

In the case of your input sequence:

```
1 dog 
2 pizza
3 cat
4 frog
5 emu
6 pizza
7 pizza
8 cat
9 emu
```

When you enter 'pizza' (6), it is correct and advances to the 2nd passcode, but then it compares 'pizza' (7) where it should be 'cat'